# Which is the difference between the swimlanes on Kanban board of the TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, kanban

On my Kanban board project I have the option to add swimlanes on the Features where all the product backlog items are and another option on the Stories side. 
Which would be the approach of each of them and why should be their separate use.

For example, I have on my Feature option an Expedited lane, does it make sense to leave it there or that options is more a swimlane that belongs to the Stories option?

As you can see I can set as many swimlanes I need, I found useful to have for example one swimlane per project on the Features option if I suppose to work with more than one at the same time, but in the other hand it gets me confused because I have the same option on Stories

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually we use Product Backlog items(PBIs) to represent the work you want to develop and ship. You track bugs, tasks, and blocking issues using the bug, task, and issue WITs. To support portfolio management, teams create features and epics to view a roll up of user stories within or across teams. We usually map some PBIs under feature. The Feature could be the Parent of PBIs.

The Expedited Swinlanes could be used to both at Feature board or Stories Board to track those workitems which are urgent. For more details, you could read this document: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/kanban/expedite-work#types-of-swimlanes

You create Swimlanes for each project also makes sense. In the Stories board, you could also create swimlanes the same like the Feature board to divided those workitems. But I suggest that you could [create a team](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scale/multiple-teams) for each project, move those corresponding workitems to each team. Or you could [create Areas](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/modify-areas-iterations#add-an-area) for each project, using Area to distinguish them

Comment: @Heinrich Did you have any other question about it?